# How to Get the length of a TypeCode

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I don't have an answer for.  Here's the senario and the question.

I have an array that was stored using in a particular format.  The format contains a Header record with muntiple detail records following it. The header of the record tells me what TypeCode was used to store the data, for instance Int32.

I have a routine that takes a byte[] array and converts the byte data back to it's proper format in C#.  This routine needs the proper number of bytes to make the conversion successful.

Q. So how can I get the length of bytes from the given TypeCode for passing to the Convert function without having to hardcode the length for every type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `TypeCode` is just an enumeration of a fixed set of values, you could easily hard-code a dictionary of them, e.g.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<TypeCode,int> TypeCodeLength =
    new Dictionary<TypeCode,int> {
    { TypeCode.Int32, 4 },
    { TypeCode.Int64, 8 },
    { TypeCode.Char, 2 },
    // etc
}
```

(An equivalent solution would be to use a switch/case statement - they really are equivalent if you're just including values.)

Some, like `string` and `object` will be variable though - and others will depend on how you're encoding things like `DateTime`.

Unless this is using a standard conversion, nothing in the framework is going to be able to give you the lengths. I know hard-coding is generally frowned upon, but in this case it's only in one place and is going to be the simplest option.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question. :)  For this implementation, it seems like you could use a model like a BSTR where the first four bytes of the array represent the length of the type or some such convention like that.

Comment: Of course, just like the switch, this breaks if a new type is introduced.

Comment: Introducing a new member to an enum is *always* a breaking change. I don't expect the TypeCode enum to change any time soon... Microsoft aren't likely to want to break the code of every developer who is switching on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to create Type from TypeCode...](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2148838.php), you can't (without a exhaustive switch).  Of course the other direction (Type->TypeCode) is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Answers have already be given, but I give the complete routine below to be reused by who would need it :

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for manipulations at but level
/// </summary>
public static class BitHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a TypeCode bytes length
    /// See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netcore-3.1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeCode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte GetTypeCodeByteLength(TypeCode typeCode)
    {
        byte bytesLength = 0;

        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Object:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            case TypeCode.DBNull:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                bytesLength = 1;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Char:
                bytesLength = 2;
                break;
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                bytesLength = 1;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                bytesLength = 1;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                bytesLength = 2;
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                bytesLength = 2;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                bytesLength = 8;
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                bytesLength = 8;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Single:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                bytesLength = 8;
                break;
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                bytesLength = 16;
                break;
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                bytesLength = 8;
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                bytesLength = 4;
                break;
            default:
                // Error
                break;
        }

        return bytesLength;
    }
}
```

Regards